# How to pass secure parameters to onSchedule firebase function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, environment

I am writing a firebase function using the `onSchedule` handlers from the firebase sdk.
The thing is that the function I am writing requires the use of sensitive information, and I don't want this into the codebase.

Looking at the firebase functions documentation for [Configuring Your Environment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#secret_parameters), I need to be able to use the `runWith` parameters from the `v2` firebase functions api, because those environment / parametrized variables needs to be bound to the function that is going to use them.

It seems the `onSchedule` handler cannot be used when using the `runWith` parameter from `firebase-functions`, I can only use the `https`, `pubsub` etc... handlers with it.

Is this not yet supported or is there another way to achieve the same thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `.env` file and put all of your sensitive information there. Then access the environment variables as shown below.

```
const { onSchedule } = require("firebase-functions/v2/scheduler");

const PRIVATE_CREDENTIAL = process.env.PRIVATE_CREDENTIAL

exports.scheduledFunction = onSchedule("5 11 * * *", async (event) => {
// ...
});
```

or if you prefer using **secrets**:

```
const { onSchedule } = require("firebase-functions/v2/scheduler");
const { defineSecret } = require('firebase-functions/params');
const ApiKey = defineSecret('API_KEY');

exports.schedule = onSchedule({secrets:[ApiKey], schedule:"5 11 * * *" },
async (event) => {
// ...
})
```

Check out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.scheduler) for further information.

Comment: Wouldn't the `.env` file have to be checked in into the repo? Also I don't think the `onSchedule` handler offers the first parameter for secrets, at least I can't see its declaration anywhere.

Comment: You will need to add the `.env` file to `.gitignore`, but firebase functions will be deployed together with the `.env` variables. The onSchedule trigger does take options as the first parameter or the cron syntax, I have updated my answer with reference.